# How to create module with react components and load with react lazy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i had tried to load module in react lazy but it was undefined component.

My Module file products/index.js

```
import Categories from './Category/Categories';
import Brands from './Brand/Brands';   

export default [Categories,Brands];
```

In Router file i tried like that,

```
const products = React.lazy(() => import('./views/products'));
```

but,

```
console.log(products[0]) // undefined
console.log(products[1]) // undefined
```

Is there any problem in module file? and how to achieve this with react lazy and Suspense?

Comment: Here is CRA Documentation of React Lazy and Suspense [CRA - Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy).

Comment: Did you provide a Suspense tag around the lazy loaded component?

Comment: yes i used suspense tag

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
React.lazy(() => import('./views/products').then(module => ({ default: module.Categories}));
```

Comment: this not worked. any changes need in module export?

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution, i had updated in index.js and Router.js files.

In products/index.js file

```
import Categories from './Category/Categories';
import Brands from './Brand/Brands';   

export const modules={Categories : Categories,Brands : Brands};

export default ProductModule = ({ component, path, isPrivate, ...rest }) =>{ 
   let RouteComponent=modules[component];   
   return (<Route path={path} component={RouteComponent}  {...rest}/>);     
}
```

In Router.js

```
 const ProductModule = React.lazy(() => import('./views/products'));
```

then use this like,

```
  <ProductModule path='/product/brands' component="Brands"/>
```

so it works fine.